# .net regex meaning of [^\\.]+

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a question about a regex. Given this part of a regex:

```
(.[^\\.]+)
```

The part `[^\.]+` Does this mean get everything until the first dot? So with this text:

Hello my name is Martijn. I live in Holland.

I get 2 results: both sentences. But when I leave the + sign, I get 2 two characters: `he`, `ll`, `o<space>`, `my`, etc. Why is that?

Comment: Note that `[^\.]+` and `[^\\.]+` are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `.[^\\.]+` means:

1. Match any character
2. Match any character until you get slash  or a dot ".". Note that `[^\\.]` means NOT slash or NOT dot, which means either a dot or a slash is not a match. It will keep on matching characters until it founds a dot or slash because of the "+" at the end. It is called a greedy quantifier because of that.

When you input (quotes not included): "Hello my name is Martijn. I live in Holland." 
The matches are:

1. Hello my name is Martijn
2. . I live in Holland

Note that the dot is not included in the first match since it stops at n in Martijn and the second match starts with the dot.

When you remove the +: (`.[^\\.]`)
It just means:

1. Match any character
2. Match any character except a dot or a slash.

Answer (score 2):

Because a [dot outside a character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (ie, not between []) means (almost) any character.

So, `.[^\\.]` means match **(almost) any character** followed by something which is **not a dot nor a backslash** (dots don't need to be escaped in a character class to mean just a dot, but backslashes do),

This, in your example, is h (any character) e (not a dot nor a backslash) and so on and so forth.

Whereas with a + (one or more of not a dot nor a backslash) you will match all characters which are not dots until a dot.

Comment: Might be a faulty copy and past since the OP posted both `[^\\.]` and `[^\.]` in his question. But no, `[^\.]` doesn't match (almost) any character except a dot or a backslash. It matches (almost) any character except a dot (the backslash can be omitted in this case). If a backslash should be included, it has to be escaped: `[^\\.]`.

Comment: Backslash escaping depends heavily on the language/platform. So it can mean both, depending on how does your regex engine (or language feeding it) interprets strings and backslashes

Comment: Okay, but in most PCRE implementations, you need to escape the '\', whether it's in- or outside a character class. And I can't imagine ASP (the OP flagged the question as such) would match a backslash using the class: **[\]**

Answer (score 1):

The regex means:
**any one character** followed by **more than zero characters that are not a backslash or a period**.